# Will altering order of columns in GROUP BY affect performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, azure-sql-database, query-performance

I have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT A, B, (CASE WHEN C=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), COUNT(D)
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY A, B, (CASE WHEN C=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
```

On a huge dataset the actual execution plan attributes most of the time to a node that corresponds to *logical operation Aggregate* and *physical operation HashMatch*.

Will changing the order in which the columns and conditions are listed in the `GROUP BY` list affect performance?

Answer (score 7):

Despite what MSDN documentation says, no, it doesn't matter for `GROUP BY` queries.

You can test it here, at: [SQL-Fiddle test (SQL-Server 2012)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0584e/1)

```
CREATE TABLE test
( id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
, a  INT NOT NULL
, b  INT NOT NULL
, c  INT NOT NULL
, d  INT NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX a_b_c_include_d_index
    ON test (a, b, c)
    INCLUDE (d) ;

INSERT INTO test
(a, b, c, d)
VALUES
 ... some 50K rows
```

The queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num
     , MIN(cnt) AS min_count
     , MAX(cnt) AS max_count
     , MIN(min_d) AS min_min_d
     , MAX(min_d) AS max_min_d
     , MIN(max_d) AS min_max_d
     , MAX(max_d) AS max_max_d
FROM
  ( SELECT a
         , b
         , c
         , COUNT(d) AS cnt
         , MIN(d) AS min_d
         , MAX(d) AS max_d
    FROM test 
    GROUP BY a, b, c             --- or with:  `GROUP BY b, a, c`
  ) AS grp ;
```

produce the same execution plan:

[image: execution plan]

```
MICROSOFT SQL SERVER 2005 XML SHOWPLAN
SELECT
Compute Scalar
Cost: 0%
Stream Aggregate
(Aggregate)
Cost: 0%
Compute Scalar
Cost: 10%
Stream Aggregate
(Aggregate)
Cost: 10%
Index Scan
[a_b_c_include_d_index].[test]
Cost: 89%
```

---

Now if you change that Group by to:

```
    GROUP BY a, b, c
      WITH ROLLUP
```

it does make a difference and it does produce different execution plans (and different result sets of course). It still uses the index though, at least in that SQL-Fiddle test. It the mismatching order case, it gets the data from the index but it has to do an intermediate sort (to calculate the rollup values).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you have an index covering those columns.

According to the [documentation over at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172984.aspx):

In the context of multiple-column indexes, for ORDER-BY or GROUP-BY to consider a particular index, the ORDER-BY or GROUP-BY columns must match the prefix set of index columns with the exact order. For example, the index

```
CREATE INDEX Emp_Name ON Employees ("Last Name" ASC, "First Name" ASC)
```

can help optimize the following queries:

```
... ORDER BY / GROUP BY "Last Name" ...
... ORDER BY / GROUP BY "Last Name", "First Name" ...
```

It will not help optimize:

```
... ORDER BY / GROUP BY "First Name" ...
... ORDER BY / GROUP BY "First Name", "Last Name" ...
```

Comment: `GROUP BY "First Name", "Last Name"` is the same as `GROUP BY "Last Name", "First Name"`, no? So as per WHERE and ON, order doesn't matter. For ORDER BY, it does

Comment: The documentation you link to is for SQL Server Compact 4.0

Comment: @MartinSmith: In Jason's favour, the documentation for 2008 version has the same thing.

Comment: @ypercube - link? clicking the "other versions" selector doesn't seem to work for me. It still takes me to an article discussing SQL Server Compact specifically. No idea whether it is true for the compact versions or not either but maybe they do have a more primitive optimiser.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Oh you are right, yes, missed that line. So, can we assume that it depends on the version of the SQL-Server? If yes, what about the Azure? I can't find documenation.